# Is it possible with highcharts to add specific custom label on yAxis label for specific plot only?

Tags: highcharts

I am looking for solution to add custom text labels on yAxis with highcharts for selected plot only.

I have 3 plot items/legends among which one should have custom string to show on yAxis instead of default values and rest keep showing default label at yAxis.

I know we can use this

```
 yAxis: {
    categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas']
  },
```

but this is going to show the categories/yAxis label with all plot/legends values, I want to show above categories with specific plot/legends only. Such that if any one click load page, chart show the provided data with default labels but clicking on this plot will show yAxis label provided by me.

I am using spline highchart.

You can find similar example here:

```
https://www.highcharts.com/demo/spline-plot-bands
```

The chart on the link mentioned above have 2 bands and its y-axis is showing plot-bands. In my case, I have total of 3 bands (say yellow, black and blue bands) to show among them plot bands is required to show with only 1 band (blue band). So when user click on blue band only then plot bands should appear on the chart.

I have total of 7 charts. Among them 2 of them are not going to have blue band and the whole code is centralised so I am not using separate code for each chart.

Thanks

Comment: Can you make a live example, e.g. on jsfiddle? You can use [yAxis.labels.formatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.labels.formatter) for dynamically changing labels in y axis.

Comment: @morganfree I have added an example in my question above. Its not in jsfiddle. If I was able to do it in jsfiddle, I would have no point in asking the question in the first place.